# Could I read Trials of Apollo directly after PJ and Olympians?

Tags: reading-order, rick-riordan, the-trials-of-apollo

I read all of the first series, *Percy Jackson and the Olympians*. Years later I’m picking it back up. I didn’t know they all tied into each other, but anyhow I picked up the Trials of Apollo. Did I miss events that led to the Trials of Apollo?

Answer (score 0):

**Not really, no, you can't read it directly after *Percy Jackson and the Olympians***.

The events of *The Trials of Apollo* start right after the events of *The Heroes of Olympus*. It focuses on characters that you won't be familiar with, and you'll lack some essential knowledge about what's going on.

For a concrete example, the whole storyline of Leo will make no sense if you haven't read HoO.

So **no, you must read *The Heroes of Olympus* before *The Trials of Apollo*.**

Comment: Answering and then closing as a dupe of something you answered ... tut tut ;-)